# Accept a regular expression and produce an NFA (Java)

Tags: java, regex, parsing, nfa

I am trying to write a program that will accept a string that describes a regular expression.  For instance:

```
10(0U1)*
```

Where the U is the union operator and the * is the Kleene star (we also see implied concatenation).

I considered tokenizing the atoms of the string and constructing the machine based on the operators and operands.  I wanted to algorithmically operate on each atom with rules similar to this: http://www.cs.may.ie/staff/jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node5.html

I am not sure how I can best parse this type of input in an intelligent manner so that I can programmatically construct an NFA.

The goal of my program will be to take in the input described above and output the corresponding NFA that will be described by its 5-touple.  Any advice on reaching that goal is much appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to implement an NFA... how will it operate?  Will you have massively parallel hardware to run it on?  Or will you internally convert first to a DFA?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've studied computational theory. :)  Is there an "order of operations" in these regular expressions?  If so, I would probably start there with my parsing (i.e., let's say Union has the highest order of precedence... then find all the Unions, perform those operations, go to the next operator, etc.)

Comment: bdares: There's an almost trivial algorithm for simulating an NFA (Algorithm 3.4 in the Dragon, though some variant can be found in most algorithms textbooks); it's often used to introduce the concept of a deque, (since it fits quite naturally, though the Dragon algorithm just uses two stacks). Back in the days when grep, egrep and fgrep were all separate programs, grep used it (after generating an NFA by Thompson's construction).

Answer (score 2):

If you can use external libraries, you are better off having a modern parser generator such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) do all the parsing work and hand you an abstract syntax tree for your regular expression, even if it's a relatively simple language.

Otherwise, if you need to write it from scratch, you need to first figure out if you need a tokenizer (or "lexical analyser"). If your language is made of one-char tokens (as in your example) then you can safely skip writing a tokenizer and just loop over the chars in the string. Then you'll have to write the parser, a big loop that scans the token list and builds a syntax tree.

In any case you should end up with a syntax tree like this, for your example `10(0U1)*`:

[image: syntax tree]

Notice that in the syntax tree all parentheses and implicit precedence rules are gone, they are replaced by the tree's structure.

After that, you'll have to recursively translate the tree into an NFA graph.

Here's a rough sketch of **one possible way** to proceed.

Write a translation method for each syntax node type. The method will be called with its starting and ending NFA states as arguments, the latter being optional. The method will draw its own piece of the graph, calling the translation method of its children as appropriate, and return its ending state (which may have been omitted as a parameter, thus unknown to its caller.)

- Create a beginning state and call the translation method for the root node of the syntax tree, passing it the beginning state as its starting state.
- A literal syntax node (0 and 1 in your example) will draw an arrow from its starting state to its ending state, creating a new ending state if not supplied:
  [image]
- A star node will call its child node's translation method giving its own starting state as both starting and ending state for the child (so that the NFA will be able to "loop" over this state as many times as needed.)
- A concat node will call the first child, giving it its starting state but no ending state; then it will call the 2nd child, passing it the 1st child's ending state as the starting one; and so on, building a one-way sequence of sub-graphs, one per child.

You should get the idea.

After you have built the NFA graph as a linked structure of states (and maybe displayed it as an actual graph, for debugging or documentation purposes) you can translate it into the formal tuple and output it.